# JDK9 Automatic Modules and "Split Packages" Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, java-9, hamcrest, java-module

I am converting a java project to use modules. One of my modules depends on `hamcrest` library, and it needs both of the jar files `hamcrest.core` and `hamcrest.library`. These two jar files both have `org.hamcrest` package. So when my module wants to treat these two jars as automatic modules, it fails because two modules in a module-path cannot have packages with same name. I searched a lot and found some related stuff on stackoverflow. It seems that I have two reasonable options if I do not want to rebuild those dependencies:

1. Merge the two jars into one jar using my build automation tool (which is maven).
2. Somehow tell java compiler that these two jars should be treated as a single automatic module.

So here are my questions:

- Is any of these two options possible? If yes, how?
- Is there any better option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The cleanest of all solutions would be to report and get it fixed in the library itself. Some links/reports useful in such cases -https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/187, https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/205

Comment: That's right for sure but I am in hurry :)

Comment: Did you try to let those jars remain on the *classpath* instead of *modulepath* to result into an unnamed module? Not sure though [that would be something you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828014/how-split-packages-are-avoided-in-java-9).

Comment: Unfortunately explicit module cannot read classpath. It says if the explicit module is treatd as unnamed module "TEMPORARILY", that would work but I've no idea what this even means!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I finally managed to solve it like this:

1. Create a new maven module called `hamcrest-all` and add dependencies on `hamcrest-core` and `hamcrest-library`.
2. add `maven-assembly-plugin` to this module with `appendAssemblyId` set to false.
3. remove the dependency to `hamcrest-core` and `hamcrest-library` from other maven modules and instead add dependency to `hamcrest-all`.
4. exclude `hamcrest-core` and `hamcrest-library` when including dependency to `hamcrest-all`.

What it actually does is that it unpacks `hamcrest-core` and `hamcrest-library` in the jar file created for `hamrest-all`. And because each jar file is treated as one module by JMPS, the problem is gone :)