# Module reads package ... from both java.base and api.classic

Tags: maven, javafx, java-module, rserve

I am programming my fisrt JavaFX v17.0 project using Maven under Intellij. Everything was fine, I was able to create a JavaFX view-controller and to display it. But the problem came when I added these lines to the module-info :

```
 requires Rserve;
 requires REngine;
```

Which corresponds to those dependencies in the pom.xml:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.rosuda.REngine/Rserve -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.rosuda.REngine</groupId>
            <artifactId>Rserve</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.rosuda.REngine/REngine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.rosuda.REngine</groupId>
            <artifactId>REngine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I compile, I get these errors :

```
...
Checking sources
Copying resources... [first-javafx-try]
Parsing java... [first-javafx-try]
java: the unnamed module reads package java.io from both api.classic and java.base
java: the unnamed module reads package java.lang from both api.classic and java.base
java: module api.classic reads package java.lang from both java.base and api.classic
java: module api.classic reads package java.io from both java.base and api.classic
java: module REngine reads package java.lang from both java.base and api.classic
java: module REngine reads package java.io from both java.base and api.classic
java: module Rserve reads package java.lang from both java.base and api.classic
java: module Rserve reads package java.io from both java.base and api.classic
Checking dependencies... [first-javafx-try]
...
```

I tried adding these lines to the vm configuration :

```
--add-exports java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
```

But it still doesn't work.

Could you provide some explanation about the source of the errors and a way to solve them please ?

### UPDATE

In fact, the dependencies RServe and REngine are not modularized, but I don't know how to deal with that.

For more information, here is the full pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.rosuda.REngine/Rserve -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.rosuda.REngine</groupId>
            <artifactId>Rserve</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.rosuda.REngine/REngine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.rosuda.REngine</groupId>
            <artifactId>REngine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.demo/root.circlepong.CirclePongApp</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And the module-info :

```
module root {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    
    requires Rserve;
    requires REngine;

    opens root.circlepong to javafx.fxml;
    exports root.circlepong;

    opens root.switchscene to javafx.fxml;
    exports root.switchscene;

    opens root.mvvmfxFirsttry to javafx.fxml;
    exports root.mvvmfxFirsttry;
}
```

### UPDATE 2

When running the compile command, I found out that Intellij runs the command :

```
C:\Users\Thibault\.jdks\openjdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52247:D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Programmation\MASI1.5\CarteAPuce\JavaCardsTools\lib\api_classic-3.1.0.jar;D:\JavaProg\MASI_Projet_Integre\mavenJava11Project\target\classes;C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-17.0.6\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-17.0.6\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-17.0.6\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-17.0.6\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-17.0.6\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-17.0.6\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-17.0.6\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-17.0.6\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\Users\Thibault\.m2\repository\org\rosuda\REngine\Rserve\1.8.1\Rserve-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\Thibault\.m2\repository\org\rosuda\REngine\REngine\2.1.0\REngine-2.1.0.jar" root.switchscene.SwitchSceneApp --module-path C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-17.0.6\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Here we can see that there is the jar 'api_classic-3.1.0.jar' in the classpath but I never specified it, how can I remove that from the automatic command ?

Comment: Please provide your full pom.xml file and module-info.java file.

Comment: Where does module `api.classic` come from? (I don't see it referenced in either of the dependencies that you mention, but I could have missed something).

Comment: The general problem is described at [How split packages are avoided in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828014/how-split-packages-are-avoided-in-java-9) and [bridges to the classpath](https://openjdk.org/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#bridges-to-the-class-path), but you really shouldn't have something called `api.classic` that includes classes that are in the same package as classes in `java.base`.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use the `ea` versions of JavaFX unless you need the "early access" functionality they provide.  Instead, use versions that don't have `ea` in the name.  Using `ea` versions of previously released software, for which there are non `ea` versions available, like JavaFX 17, provides no value and could generate unforeseen issues.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the problems come from the 'D:\Programmation\MASI1.5\CarteAPuce\JavaCardsTools\lib\api_classic-3.1.0.jar' jar added. As I was not able to remove theline from the Intellij automatic command, I deleted the jar and now everything works fine. This is probably not the best way to do it, but it works.

Comment: It seems the [`api_classic-3.1.0.jar`](https://www.javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?t=2168) is for the [JavaCardOS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card), a stripped down version of Java for smart cards, that is likely incompatible with the module system in the full Java SE version.